# Data in ajax and fetch are diiferent

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ajax, post, fetch

I have a ajax function like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'remove',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                contact: rahul,
                type: 'call'
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log("work");
            }
        });
```

But when I use the same thing for fetch it is not working.

```
   const data = {
        contact: rahul,
        type: 'call'
    }
    fetch('remove', {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').content
        },
    })
```

I think the data is not passing. But what wrong am I doing?

Comment: Did you mean to not include quotes in the 1st block? `data: {contact: rahul, type: call}` instead of `data: {contact: 'rahul', type: 'call'}`

Comment: @dabishan Sorry, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've not stringify your data. try this,

```
fetch('remove', {    // assuming remove is your api endpoint
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').content
  },

  //make sure to serialize your JSON body
  body: JSON.stringify({
    contact: rahul,
    type: call,
  })
})
.then( (response) => { 
   //do something here
});
```

Hope it helps!!